# WebStorm doesn't understand Angular 2 syntax

Tags: angular, webstorm

I have installed Angular CLI and generated new project. I'm working in WebStorm, and it seems like it doesn't understand Angular 2 syntax (highlights `*ngFor` for example) and there is no autocomplete.

[image]

Can someone please help to get autocomplete and correct highlight for Angular 2 code and html tags/attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Webstorm 16.1 doesn't work with Angular 2 correctly. Working with Angular presents like a feature of 17.1 version. From [Webstorm website](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/) (17.1 release): "WebStorm provides advanced coding assistance for Angular, React, Vue.js and Meteor...". The update to latest version for now (2017.1) solved my problem.

Comment: Bummer, sorry my answer didn't help. I am using Intellij 17, but I thought some of the template stuff worked in 16.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your try. `Angular` plugin is really the first, what I need to check, I just forget to write that I already use it, my fault